# Javascript - Searching For Specific Objects & Finding Objects With Mostly Correct Matches

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, object, search

What's up, I've got a general js question that I've been struggling with. Not quite sure how to do this, but I have an array of objects like this

```json
{
      "postHeight": "5",
      "type": "CL",
      "barb": "None"
      (Actual object will have around 20-30 properties to search through)
}
```

I also have a search function that allows you to search through these objects to find the right one. There will be hundreds of these objects in the array, so if I want to find one specific object with a postHeight of `6`, a type of `CL`, and a barb of `straight`, it will find the object where all of those match up, and then push that entire object that matched, to a different array. Easy enough. My main problem is that I want to be able to tell the user, if only objects' `postHeight` and `type` match their inputs without `barb` matching their inputs, that `No exact matches found, but there is a match that has the correct postHeight and type, just with an incorrect barb.`

I'm not quite sure how I should be going about doing that, though. There could be 15 objects with matching `postHeights` and 20 with matching `type`s, but I want to find the object with the most amount of matches, and then tell the users exactly which properties match, and which ones don't match their search query.

The object used in this question only has 3 properties but we'll most likely have more around the 20-30 range for each object

Comment: You could return an array of objects along with the number of fields that matched the criteria. Then you can sort the array by this count.

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the array of objects by how many fields match:

```js
const data = [
  {
        "postHeight": "6",
        "type": "CL",
        "barb": "straight"
  },
  {
        "postHeight": "5",
        "type": "CL",
        "barb": "straight"
  },
  {
        "postHeight": "6",
        "type": "SA",
        "barb": "straight"
  },
  {
        "postHeight": "6",
        "type": "CL",
        "barb": "None"
  }
]

const search = (obj) => {
    const entries = Object.entries(obj);
    const searchKeys = Object.keys(obj);
    return data.map((el) => {
        const matched = entries.filter(([k, v]) => el[k] === v);
        return { count: matched.length, ...el, unmatched: searchKeys.filter(k => el[k] !== obj[k]) }
    }).sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count);
}


console.log(search({postHeight: "6", type: "CL", barb: "straight"}));
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like it would be viable if we decided to add more properties. With this intersection method, it would work with the current number, but we'll most likely be adding a lot more properties to each object as time goes on. Perhaps I should edit that into my original post

Comment: Changed it to a different approach